# Edge17 - SEC7136 - The origin failed an integrity check for a resource

Tags: browser, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, content-security-policy, subresource-integrity

In a jekyll website, I added a plugin (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/), everything is working fine upto Edge16 & below browsers, however, in Edge17, I see the console message:

`SEC7136: [Integrity] The origin '[insert url]' failed an integrity check for a style resource at '[url]'`

What is this error about? And how is the offending file, in this case, a CSS file, causing an integrity issue in Edge17 & not the previous version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in 1803 Win10 release. You are probably importing a CSS stylesheet and even though the parent has good integrity Edge regards the imported stylesheet as "Bad" integrity and blocks it - Which is not correct and hence a bug. This should be fixed in the upcoming Windows release.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this has been a bit frustrating, finding info on this message.

Comment: Welcome. It's frustrating I understand especially because of very less devs working with this Browser.

Comment: Even this website will fail to work: https://portal.my.uq.edu.au/#/dashboard due to this bug

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug with the OS. It's actually a security feature. When you load an external JavaScript or CSS resource from a CDN, there is an attribute for integrity. If the values aren't correct, the resource will not load. This is a protection against unexpected or malicious third party modification. It appears that this validation is now enforced in Edge.

To fix, all you have to do is update your CDN references in your code, and be sure to include the correct integrity and crossorigin attributes.

[Here is an excellent resource that explains in detail.](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/subresource-integrity-in-firefox-43/)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I am looking into this now.

Comment: This is correct. But the context for which this was raised was the parent CSS file has the "accepted" integrity. Now when this parent CSS files (child CSS file) tries to load any other CSS file which doesn't have this integrity field is failing on Edge. As per standard even the child CSS file should be considered as "acceptable" integrity and should load properly on a browser (like it does on Chrome). However Edge doesn't entertain this - which is a bug with Edge. The upcoming Win10 feature release would solve this bug. So my answer was correct for the question asked. Thanks

Comment: @Kayote If you happen to have a latest Win 10 insider preview build from Fast Track. You will be able to load this URL properly on Edge ::: https://portal.my.uq.edu.au/#/dashboard